# Running Macbook (2007) on 12vdc with correct wattage car charger - why is it blowing an 8A fuse?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

Short version: Does the Macbook somehow draw more than 60W while in use?

We live in a house with a small solar power system. We've been here for 7 years and for most of that time have successfully run our (now rather elderly) Macbook on the 12v system. We do have 240v inverter to run the washing machine and food processor but it's pretty inefficient and not the right kind of sine wave for digital stuff anyway. So we use a car charger (not apple, obviously) to step up to 16.5v (giving 60w).

It charges the laptop fine and as far as I'm aware we've not managed to damage the laptop..! We noticed that the house lights flicker a little if we are using the computer while it's plugged in in the evening. I assumed this meant we were drawing too much power for the system, so we'd either switch most of the lights off or unplug the laptop. However, in the last couple of days it's started blowing the 8A socket fuse, which puzzles me. I've tried a couple of different sockets and measured the voltage at each. The voltage is above 12v (reading the same as the house battery) and the fuse blows at both.

Surely the laptop should never be drawing more than 5A at the most? The interesting bit is that it only does if we're USING it while it's plugged in. If it's sleeping/off and charging, it's fine. Sadly, the battery no longer lasts long enough to use it while not plugged in, particularly if we're streaming TV/films. So I suppose my Mac-specific question is does the Macbook somehow draw more than 60W while in use...? Or can someone tell me why else it might be blowing an 8A fuse..?

Comment: What kind of sine wave do you need for "digital stuff" that an inverter just won't provide?

Comment: Some inverters produce really nasty square waves as an approximation of sine waves. http://www.xantrex.com/documents/Tech-Doctor/Universal/Tech1-Universal.pdf **and** https://www.lifewire.com/modified-sine-wave-inverter-damage-question-534760 That can be very hard on elctronic devices.

Answer (score -1):

You are using a 12V car charger and stepping up the voltage to 16V and it's melting?

It's melting because it's passing way more power than it can possibly handle.  What amperage is it rated for?  I would bet 500mA or 1A max.  It's melting and shorting out.  The question here is why don't you have a car charger cable with an *inline fuse*?

To get 60W on a 12V circuit, you need a 5A rating.

Your MacBook ***REQUIRES*** 60W @ 16.5V so it needs 3.65A.   If you puling 5A off 12V adapter then boosting to 16.5V you are overworking that charger.  Additionally, without know what you have done to convert that 12V to 16V (I am praying you didn't do a DIY hookup) you may be dumping very "dirty" power directly into your MacBook.  This is why you need a switching power supply.

So, your MacBook will not draw more than 60W otherwise it will be over rated for the power adapter they supplied you.  The light flickering you are seeing is probably from the shorting of your 12V car charger.

You should be using an 12V DC to 110V INVERTER as well as a proper MacBook Power Adapter.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is possible for the MacBook to draw more than 60W in heavy usage. I don't have specific numbers for your model (you do not list if you have a mid 2007 or late 2007) - but I once measured the early 2008 MacBook to draw 90W at max.

You can look at Activity Monitor to determine which app is using the power (i.e. which one is hogging up the CPU).

Comment: Apple will ***NOT*** sell you an adapter which will not supply the required current, so it will not draw more than what it is rated for.  The mid and late 2007 MacBook (no MBP that year) uses the 60W adapter.  Activity Monitor does absolutely nothing to tell you what your power draw at the adapter is.

Comment: @Allan I didn't say that activity monitor tells you what the power draw at the adapter is. However, it does tell you which applications are using a lot of power - i.e. you can identify what is causing the high usage of CPU and perhaps eliminate that to get rid of the problem.

Comment: @Allan And yes, the Apple supplied adapter should never use more power than the listed rating on it. However I gathered from the question that he's not using the official Apple charger, but something different.